# Python requests - JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: json, python-3.x, utf-8, python-requests

I'm trying to grab a response from an api but i cannot load it in a dictionary.

Here's my code:

```
r = session.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

The returned `status code` is `200` so i get a response.

By trying to do: `reply = r.json()` i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/honeymonitor/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    data = get_data(session)
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/honeymonitor/main.py", line 35, in get_data
    reply = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\honeymonitor\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And by using `reply = r.text` i get a lot of gibberish:

```
� d�M���)b�b��$�j�np������X2�Al�w{g��wO�n-���w��g�����}�1�Y5@�R��/�
�   X���o]>6,�N�_#�#Ң����K�@���s
��Ɩ�ː�����2��N�:D��p�����7{K��������V��
-")�p0n@I�f!���Q�+| /We�.�p�=����u���-�ʌ�cs�"jfH����}qkː��q�,q�bږq�ٟ��Z���>��U#�����ET�V/��+cU����ʁ�LLe��(���V�2���å}�UC���@�8y��B�7Λ��c���Y?��q��TOMTv{����ߎ������,�[�|��wf_�˰�g������?
```

The content type in the headers of the post request is:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
```

Also by checking the `r.encoding` i get `None`

At the end i've tried `json.loads(r.text)` but i get the same error.
Also tried encoding the response with `r.content.decode('utf-8')`
and got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've tried replicating the request with Fiddler and i can clearly see the response json there

I've compared the response headers between Fiddler and requests, the only difference is that with requests i ge `'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'` in the headers

EDIT2:

Here's a portion of the `r.content`:

````
b'\x03\xd5\x01\x00d\xca9\x9cvwC\x7f \x1b]j\xfb\xc5\xa3tA\xa1k.N9\x01\x08\x03\r\xcc\x02i\x01\xb7\x0b\xc2=\xc6\x92\xb1\rb\xe3\xbf\xdb;\x83\xb7\xbf{\xe2vk\xd1\xed\xef\xbf[d<{.n\x7fo\xd5WC\xab\x84\xeb\xecN\xd3#\xcc\xed\x0cAks\xa5\xe6\x87?\x15\xb3:\x8d\xfdS}\xb5O\x9a\xb8\x9d\xddK\x98\xf5+HSLq\x14\x84\xab:Fd!\xa8\xc0\x0c\xd2\xd3\x0eL\xd4\xec\x9b\xcb\xf2\xcf\xae\x18\xd9\x15&fg\xbf\xd6.```
````

Comment: Is there a 'Content-Encoding' header?  If so, what is its value?

Comment: No, there's not

Comment: I've edited the question, added some useful information i think

Comment: Could you show the first 100 bytes of r.content?

Comment: Until you have converted the gibberish to string, you won't be able to parse it. I suspect the response is compressed, but the server erroneously does not declare that fact, so `requests` does not transparently uncompress the data for you. What does `r.raw` show?

Comment: Here's a portion of the r.content:
`b'\x03\xd5\x01\x00d\xca9\x9cvwC\x7f \x1b]j\xfb\xc5\xa3tA\xa1k.N9\x01\x08\x03\r\xcc\x02i\x01\xb7\x0b\xc2=\xc6\x92\xb1\rb\xe3\xbf\xdb;\x83\xb7\xbf{\xe2vk\xd1\xed\xef\xbf[d<{.n\x7fo\xd5WC\xab\x84\xeb\xecN\xd3#\xcc\xed\x0cAks\xa5`\xe6\x87?\x15\xb3:\x8d\xfdS}\xb5O\x9a\xb8\x9d\xddK\x98\xf5+HSLq\x14\x84\xab:Fd!\xa8\xc0\x0c\xd2\xd3\x0eL\xd4\xec\x9b\xcb\xf2\xcf\xae\x18\xd9\x15&fg\xbf\xd6.`

Comment: It looks like a compressed (possibly gzipped) content

Answer (score 0):

There can be a couple of reasons for this error 
I faced the same error. In my case, I am calling a `put` URL. In your case, it is `post`
I implemented my put API in such a way that, it won't return anything except status code. So after receiving the Response body contains `no data`. And we are trying to parse that to JSON. But actually nothing is there to parse.

Comment: with fiddler i got data to parse, it's strange that with python doesn't work